# HTML copy image from canvas to another canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to generate a image from first canvas and then draw in the another canvas, but i have a problem because i don't know why i don't see nothing in the other canvas. It's my code:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="704" height="608" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // prepaire our game canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = 2048;
        ctx.canvas.height = 2048;   

        var rows = 64;
        var columns = 64;
        this.image = new Image();
        var imageObject = document.createElement("img");
        var me = this;

        /// need this as loading is async
        imageObject.onload = function() {    
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {        
                for (var j=0; j <columns; j++) {  
                    ctx.drawImage(this, i*32,j*32,32,32); 
                }   
            }       
            // store the generate map as this image texture
            me.image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");                 
        }

        imageObject.src='ground.jpg';
        this.image.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");     


        context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, 300, 300, 0, 0, 300,300);       
</script>
```

Please for advice why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

After creating DOM element, you should append it on the other element to display it.

Try this

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pL3GP/1/)

script:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var image=document.createElement("img");
        image.onload=function(){ 
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height=image.height;
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); 
            var tcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var tctx = tcanvas.getContext('2d');
            tcanvas.width = 8*image.width;
            tcanvas.height = 8*image.height;
            for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(var j=0;j<8;j++){
                      tctx.drawImage(image, i*image.width,j*image.height); 
                    document.body.appendChild(tcanvas);
                }
            }
        }
   image.src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-L1cr04d6ONc/RsRykgOl9zI/AAAAAAAABIE/WqBGOdiJnys/s128/Finishes.Flooring.Tile.Square.Blue.bump.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are taking an unnecessary detour by converting the canvas to a DataURL and then setting the source of an image to that DataURL. This is unnecessary because `context.drawImage` can work with a `<canvas>` just like it can work with an `<img>`. You can use your background canvas (the canvas itself, not the context) as a source just like you can use an image.
2. You seem to assume that the onload-handler of an image is executed the moment you set the src-attribute. This is not the case. Your javascript code continues while the image is loaded from the server. You have no way to tell when (and if) the load-handler will actually be executed. But you are setting `this.image.src` to the dataUrl of the canvas, and then you use that image for `context.drawImage`. At that point, the canvas will likely still be empty, so the data-url will also be that of an empty image.

Solution: Put the last line of your code into the onload-function.